# traverse_ equivalent in Python?

Tags: python, haskell, foldable

In *Haskell*, we have `traverse_`, a function that works on `Foldable` types to fold a structure with an *applicative function*, discarding any result:

```
traverse_ :: (Applicative f,Foldable t) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f ()
```

So we can for instance do this:

```
traverse_ putStrLn ["Hello, ","world!"]
traverse_ print (Just 3)
```

What is the *Python* equivalent to `traverse_`? At least for lists?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Haskell, but it sounds like the Python equivalent is a `for` loop. Python's functional features are specifically not designed for operations with side effects.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a simple loop, or `list(map(...))` or a comprehension, and don't save references.

For `traverse_ putStrLn ["Hello, ","world!"]`:

```
for i in ["Hello, ", "world!"]:
    print(i)
```

or:

```
list(map(print, ["Hello, ", "world!"]))
```

or:

```
[print(i) for i in ["Hello, ", "world!"]
```

Note that `list(map(...))` and the comprehension will output the returned value `[None, None]` if you use it at the interactive interpreter. If you want to suppress it there, save a reference. If you use it in a saved script, you don't need to save a reference to suppress the output of the returned value.

Comment: Ok for the loop, but the two later would actually yield a list, right? A list of `None`?

Comment: That's right, because the calls have to actually be evaluated. Technically, `print()` also has a return value - `None`. You just don't see `None` in the interpreter after a `print()` call because it specifically skips the output if it's just `None` - you'd have to print it if you wanted to see it (try `print(print('hi'))`). It outputs `[None, None]` because that's not just `None`, it's a `list`. Again, this is just in the interactive interpreter. It's not an issue in a saved script.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this simply be a higher order function that takes as input a function a function `f`, a list `l` and calls `f` on all lists:

```
def traverse_ (f,l) :
    for li in l :
        f(li)
```

This will work on lists, tuples, generators, strings,... Which can be seen as a bit the equivalent of `Foldable`.

Using this in `python3` gives:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Mar 26 2015, 22:03:40) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def traverse_ (f,l) :
...     for li in l :
...         f(li)
... 
>>> traverse_(print,["Hello, ","world!"])
Hello, 
world!
```

`traverse_` thus basically comes down to a monadic `for` loop I think. Where the Applicative is performed on all items.

Comment: It’s not monadic, it’s applicative. I should edit my post. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand it correctly, but may be you're looking for a `map` wrapper:

```
def traverse(f):
    return lambda L : map(f, L)

print traverse(lambda x : x*x) (range(5)) # [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```